# Codeigniter routing not working in some cases?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got used to use Grocery CRUD library which eases CRUD process. When I'm going to use the edit process, The `URI` is would be some thing like `http://www.example.com/users/get_users/edit/userID(num)`.
The issue is, If one of the users removes the userID this will gives an error due to the required parameter by edit method, So that I have tried to use Codeigniter routing as below

```
$route['users/get_users/edit'] = "users/get_users";
```

But this didn't work..!

Any idea please...

Answer (score 0):

```
$route['users/get_users/edit/:num'] = "users/get_users";
```

It should be like this. And I think you getting error message because "users/get_users" still expects userID. Its better to come up with the error message as well.

Comment: Thanks for Your answer. The issue is not to route "edit" with the "userID" but to route "edit" without "userID" to avoid users playing with the URI